# API or XML: Get sentence by word service

Tags: php, javascript, xml, api, dictionary

I'm trying to find a free service that can give a sentence by word.
That could be an explanation of the word or any other sentence with this word.
Is there any free service without registration?
I thought [thefreedictionary.com](http://thefreedictionary.com) has something like that but I didn't find such kind of service on their web-site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the Wordnik API: http://developer.wordnik.com/docs.html

Specifically, check out the `word/example` endpoint:

http://developer.wordnik.com/docs.html#!/word/getExamples_get_0

FYI: the [Temboo Library](https://www.temboo.com/library/keyword/) is a great resource when you want to for APIs by topic.

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is still not clear. Once I enter the URL that is suggested, I get the result{"message": "unauthorized", "type": "error"} . The URL I enter is http://api.wordnik.com/v4/word.json/outstanding/definitions?limit=200&includeRelated=true&useCanonical=false&includeTags=false

Comment: You need to sign up for the Wordnik API and get an API key. More details, including a note from the Wordnik founder, on how to use the Wordnik API: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/wordnik-api/key/wordnik-api/t2StWtDbYYg/8wEL4akgVrQJ